# Three.js How to check when animation is end?

Tags: javascript, three.js

If I write something like this:

```
function renderuj(){           
    scene.renderer.setClearColor(0xeeeeee, 1);    
    ob1.animation.update(0.5);
    ob2.animation.update(0.5);
    scene.renderer.render(scene.scene, scene.camera);

    animationFram = requestAnimationFrame(renderuj);
}
```

the animation working in loop.
But I want to play only once and no more.
How to do that

inside the .js file where is 3D animation/object we can see this

```
animation" : [{"name":"test1","fps":24,"length":10
```

and I try add to my code something like this

```
if(temp < 10)
    temp++;
else
    cancelRequestAnimFrame(animationFram );
```

but I have only half of animation

Comment: As I have no personal experience with it I won't provide a full answer, but you probably want to use http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Animation/AnimationHandler ... you add the animation to the handler, and in your `renderuj()` loop you simply call `update()` on it; you don't need to do `cancelRequestAnimFrame()` or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what type for animation object you are using but you probably want to do something like this.

```
if ( obj.animation.time + delta < obj.animation.duration ) {
    // running
    obj.animation.update( delta );
} else {
    // finished
    obj.animation.update( obj.animation.duration - obj.animation.time );
}
```